# ¿Cómo hostear una página web estática en Amazon Lightsail con una instancia de wordpress?

Tags: apache, servidor

tengo una instancia de Wordpress en Amazon Lightsail, el Wordpress está instalado en un subdominio, usé la imágen de Bitnami que ofrece Lightsail. Quiero hostear una página estática en el dominio principal, ejemplo: "https://www.expample.com". He probado la solución que da Bitnami, de simplemente subir los archivos a la ruta: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/ he probado esto pero si accedo con mi navegador al dominio principal me da el siguiente error que aparece en la imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero solucionar esto y subir una web estática que apunte a este dominio.

Comment: configurastes el virtualhost de tu apache?

Comment: No, acabo de revisar el archivo httpd-vhosts.conf y tengo esto de server name: wordpress.example.com, para <VirtualHost *:80> y <VirtualHost *:443>

Comment: y a que ruta apuntan esos virtualhost?, agrega a tu C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\host    t.ip tu.host

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80> => DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs" <VirtualHost *:443> => DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
Creo que debería editar el archivo httpd-vhosts.conf, pero no sé que tengo poner.